# Generic interface/base class - access members without type constraints

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

Suppose I have a class structure looking like this:

```
public abstract class MyOtherBaseClass
{
  public string HelloWorld;
}
public interface MyInterface<T> where T : MyOtherBaseClass
{
  T MyObject { get; set; }
}
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> : MyInterface<T>
  where T : MyOtherBaseClass
{
  public T MyObject { get; set; }
}
public class MyImplementation : MyBaseClass<MyOtherBaseClass>
{

}
```

Is there any way I can access `MyObject` in any implementation of `MyBaseClass`? I can't use a variable of `MyBaseClass` or `MyInterface` because I have to specify type constraints, but in my case I'm not interested in specifying them since all I want to do is access the value within.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
MyBaseClass baseObject = null;
if(someCondition)
{
   baseObject = new MyImplementation();
}
else if(otherCondition)
{
   baseObject = new OtherImplementation(); //this also inherits from MyBaseClass
}
var objectValue = baseObject.MyObject;
var helloWorldValue = objectValue.HelloWorld;
```

Comment: `this also inherits from MyBaseClass` From `MyBaseClass<MyOtherBaseClass>` or from other concrete type.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan sorry, `MyBaseClass<MyOtherBaseClass>`. Each implementation can make their own derived type of `MyOtherBaseClass` and use that, eg `MyBaseClass<MyDerivedOtherBaseClass>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not entirely possible, not with generics. The type `MyBaseClass` simply does not exists. A generic type must have a generic type argument.

If you do not want to use generics, why use generics?

This could also be a valid option:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
  object MyObject { get; set; }
}
public abstract class MyBaseClass : MyInterface
{
  public object  MyObject { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, in this example you have to cast the object to a specific type.

You could also combine both techniques:

```
public interface MyInterface // This is the non-generic interface.
{
    object MyObject { get; set; }
}
public interface MyInterface<T> // This is the generic interface.

    where T : MyOtherBaseClass
{
    T MyObject { get; set; }
}
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> : MyInterface, MyInterface<T> // This class implements both the non-generic and the generic interface.
  where T : MyOtherBaseClass
{
    public T MyObject { get; set; } // Implementation of the generic property.
    object MyInterface.MyObject // Implementation of the non-generic property.
    {
        get { return MyObject; }
        set { MyObject = (T)value; }
    }
}
...
MyInterface baseObject; // The non-generic interface is used as base object.
baseObject = new MyImplementation(); // It is assigned an instance of MyImplementation which uses a generic base class.
object value = baseObject.MyObject;
```